# How do I make an image fade out but stay in place on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the [Adirondack](https://adirondack-demo.squarespace.com/) template from Squarespace, there's a banner image of a purse that does this crazy thing where you scroll down and it fades out to white, but it seems to stay in the same position even as you scrolldown. It's really hard to articulate what I'm talking about, so I included [an animated GIF of the image effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMngh.gif) I'm talking about. Does anyone have any ideas about how could I go about replicating that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is Parallax Scrolling there are a ton of tutorials and examples but here is a simple implementation

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp
>
> https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".parallax").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 350);
});
```

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530357075171-3c4b84478ebd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=b930fe4c342d9dcbee9e3b3939ccbe5f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1300&q=80");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
  Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer!